# Inf and sup methods in Sage

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, sagemath

In an exercice using Sage, I would need a method that returns the sup/inf of an interval, in such a way as to be able to use that value futher down in the code. Someting like $\mathtt{inf}([x>3])$ returns $3$ $-$ which looks ridiculous stated that way, but the interval would be given using the solve method on previously defined functions. Is there any (simple) way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: you may wish to try asking this as ask.sagemath.org.  We do have some interval stuff but I don't recall a method precisely like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm in a totally different place right now, but I'll try that as soon as I can get back to it, and edit my post if anything worthwhile comes up.